# Scapy function not returning DHCP requests from Amazon dash button

Tags: python, udp, scapy, dhcp

I'm using the scapy sniff function to use an Amazon Dash button to trigger a function. The code I'm using came essentially entirely from a solution for this on Github, with some very minor tweaks.

I've gone on wire shark and spotted the dash button's DHCP requests and pulled the button's MAC address from here, but the function still isn't returning anything.

Here's the code:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('scapy.runtime').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *

def dash_pressed():
  print 'Dash button pressed.'

def udp_filter(pkt):
  options = pkt[DHCP].options
  for option in options:
    if isinstance(option, tuple):
      if 'requested_addr' in option:
        mac_to_action[pkt.src]()
        break

mac_to_action = {'DASH_MAC_ADDRESS_HERE' : dash_pressed}
mac_id_list = list(mac_to_action.keys())

print 'Waiting for a button press...'
sniff(prn=udp_filter, store=0, filter='udp', lfilter=lambda d: d.src in mac_id_list)
```

(Replaced the MAC Address string in the mac_to_action dict)

I'm not getting any errors, just nothing coming through. When I print the sniff function it shows 0 udp packets. I've double and triple checked my MAC Address and this is definitely the source address (not that there's anyway I could mix this up with ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff anyway). Why isn't it picking up on the dash button press?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for my Amazon buttons

```
def arp_handler(pkt):
    """ Handles sniffed ARP requests """
    for layer in [ARP]:
        if pkt.haslayer(layer):
            if pkt[layer].op == 1:  #who-has request
                mac = pkt[layer].hwsrc
                # your code to handle


def main():
    sniff(prn=arp_handler, filter="arp", store=0)
```

I am not sure if the problem is in ARP / DHCP difference.
May be you run the code without root privileges or do something else that prevents scapy from working properly.